# Need to pass values from 6 columns to a variable

Tags: python-3.x

i have a CSV  file with 6 columns and i want to pass the values in each row through a loop. Kindly, help to let me know how we can implement without pandas.

```
url='https://abc/g/(col1*row1 value)'
#                        payload={"ip-address": (col2*row1  value),"user-name": "dblg_urm_scan","password": str(pass),"db-name": (col3*row1  value),"server-name": (col4*row1  value),"port": (col5*row1 value),"connection-string": (col6*row1 value)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've tried anything.
This is for you to get started :

```
with open('my_file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
         cols = line.split(';')
         print(f'{cols[1]} - {cols[2]} - {cols[3]} ...')
```